# Can Spark `lag` be used without condition?

Tags: apache-spark, lag

In Spark, `lag` is used under the restriction of `over()`, but in my situation, `over()` is not necessary. I want to calculate the difference between consecutive rows without grouping, ordering or partitioning. I know I need to use `lag` for the computation but I do not know how to do it with an 'empty' `over()`. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Side comment : without an orderBy of any kind "somewhere", dataframes are not ordered, so "consecutive rows" may not be defined. It won't crash, It will do something, but not necessarily what you expect. So, make sure that somewhere, something defines an ordering of your dataframe rows... (it might be because the input is in a format that Spark reads sequentially, and it's fine, but if, for example, it's coming out of a relational database over JDBC with no ordering, you're in for trouble).

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `lag` function without `over()`. But you can pass any literal/consent value so that it can perform `lag` function over consecutive rows without grouping ordering or partitioning.

Like Below:

```
val w = Window.orderBy(lit(1))
df.withColumn("lagOut", lag(col("<column name>"), 1).over(w))
```

Please check below link for more details:

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html